# How can I reloadData on collectionView without reloading visibleCell

Tags: ios, swift, cell, reloaddata, collectionview

how can I reloadData on collectionView without reloading visibleCell? I got one cell per page (screen size) and each cell contains some buttons and animation attached to them, my problem is that when observator notice new data from server it reloads collectionview and constraints on visible cell will back to first position which i don't want. But on the other side i want other cells to be updated.

Thank you for help

Comment: Don't use `reloadData`.  Use `performBatchUpdates`, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW7

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to update the cells in this way.

Implement the method:

```
collectionview: willDisplayCell:
```

and configure your cells in that method instead of cell for row, that way as the cell is displayed it would get the new data.